# Trying to run swiftlint through Java subprocess fails (works normally through command line)

Tags: java, process, swiftlint

I have a java program to run different kinds of linters, calling the linters as a process using ProcessBuilder. So far, other linters have worked for the most part but with swiftlint, i'm facing a strange issue

When I run it normally from the command line, with

```
swiftlint --enable-all-rules
```

It works perfectly, but executing the same through my Java subprocess utility

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("swfitlint", "--enable-all-rules");
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

It fails with the following error message

```
SourceKittenFramework/library_wrapper.swift:31: Fatal error: Loading libsourcekitdInProc.so failed
```

At first glance it seems like for some reason certain libraries are not available to the java program which are available to when firing a command through bash, but just to be
sure, I tried running the following command through my subprocess util

```
swiftlint --version

swift --version
```

Both of which worked, meaning Java does have access to swift binaries installed on my machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not still not entirely sure why this happens but i believe it's due to some kind of environment issue on my machine itself.
I tried running the same code inside of a docker container that uses the image built from the following base images

```
FROM openjdk:17-slim as java_base
FROM ghcr.io/realm/swiftlint:latest 
COPY --from=java_base /usr/local/openjdk-17 /usr/local/openjdk-17
```

and it just worked